# how to create a countdown that repeats every 48 or 72 hours

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a countdown that repeats every 24, 48 or 72 hours at midnight without moment.js

For example (example for 48 hours):

10-12-22 00:00 -> start countdown -> 47:59:59

11-12-22 22:30 -> countdown = 1:30:00

12-12-22 00:00 -> the countdown restart -> 47:59:59

I try solution only for 24 hours

I try this:

```
setInterval(function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if ((min + '').length == 1) {
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if ((sec + '').length == 1) {
    sec = '0' + sec;
  },
1000);
```

Comment: Welcome here - please describe what you have tried to achieve your goal and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Hi! I try this                                  setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }, 1000);

Comment: There are a huge number of questions already about timers and countdowns. The only difference here is that when the timer reaches zero, it needs to start again. So do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge number of questions and answers already about timers and countdowns. Pick one.

The only point of interest here is that it should to restart when the remainder gets to zero, e.g.:

```js
// Counts down period milliseconds, then restarts
function timer(period) {
  let start = new Date();
  let z = n => ('0'+n).slice(-2); 
  let zz = n => ('00'+n).slice(-3); 
  let f = ms => {
    let day = (ms / 8.64e7) | 0;
    let hr = (ms % 8.64e7) / 3.6e6 | 0;
    let min = (ms % 3.6e6) / 6e4 | 0;
    let sec = (ms % 6e4) /1e3 | 0;
    let mil = (ms % 1e3);
    return `${day} days, ${z(hr)}:${z(min)}:${z(sec)}.${zz(mil)}`;
  }
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(f(period - (Date.now() - start) % period));
  }, 1000);
}

timer(1000*5);
```

Format the output however you want, maybe floor the seconds and ditch the milliseconds.

BTW, *setInterval* is not a good way to run a timer. Use successive calls to  *setTimelout* with the lag set to about 10ms longer than the time to the next full second, minute or whatever. That way it won't be seen to miss a second (which happens with *setInteval* because it may slowly drift, as can be seen in the ms part of the above, there is always *at least* 1e3 ms between logs, usually more and sometimes a lot more, depending on how busy the system is with other tasks).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the question but perhaps try setInterval?

```js
//this will log to console after 2 days
setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Ding Dong");
    },
2*24*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: No, i don't need a console log after 2 days..i need a real countdown in real time like this: 
  setInterval(function time(){ var d = new Date(); var hours = 24 - d.getHours(); var min = 60 - d.getMinutes(); if((min + '').length == 1){ min = '0' + min; } var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds(); if((sec + '').length == 1){ sec = '0' + sec; }, 1000) ......... but this is only for 24 hours

Comment: Oh now it makes sense. Just get the pre-countdown time before setting the interval, let it count up until the time of the variable d reaches the pre-countdown, you increase the pre-countdown by 2 days, the loop goes on

Comment: Can you past code please?